# How to show tooltip instead of sum in sankey

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

How to show a tooltip which is related to that particular bar. Currently, I am able to show the tooltip between the bar. But when I hover over football or Basketball or Ronaldo or Messi instead of tooltip sum is coming. How to show tooltip instead of sum.
Basically, this is the output I want

When I hover over football I want  1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12
Similarly, when I hover over Basketball I want 11,12

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
        xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'tooltip'],
        data: [

            ['Football', 'Basketball', 20, [1,2] ],
            ['Football', 'Ronaldo', 3, [4,5,6] ],
            //['Challenged', 'Terminated', 0 ],
            ['Football', 'Other', 1, [7,8,9,11,12] ],
            ['Basketball', 'Messi', 12, [] ],
            //['Instituted', ' Terminated', 0 ],
            ['Basketball', 'Gerad', 6 , [] ],
            ['Basketball', ' Rooney', 2, [11,12] ],

        ],
        type: 'sankey',

        nodeFormat:  function () { 
   var abc = []; 
   each(node.linksTo, function (link) { abc.push(link.tooltip) });

 return abc; 
},


    }]

});
```

Comment: what you wanted to see instead is unclear. do you wanted to see `20` instead `1, 2` in case of football ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `nodeFormatter` funtion for `sankey` tooltip and create a string as you want:

```
        nodeFormatter: function() {
            var result = '';

            Highcharts.each(this.linksFrom, function(el) {
                result += (el.tooltip && result ? ',' : '') + el.tooltip;
            });

            return result;
        }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mh0ye5a7/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.tooltip.nodeFormatter

Comment: Hi Aniket Shivam Tiwari, To show name you can just `return this.name`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1tv3mcw8/. To completely hide tooltip in same cases you can wrap `refresh` method: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nphy0orf/

Answer (score -1):

There are two thing you need to do here.

1. Add the nodeFormat for tooltip on Bar it defaults to `{point.name}: <b>{point.sum}` that is why you see **sum** everytime you moseover the bar

   pointFormat: '{point.fromNode.name} → {point.toNode.name} {point.tooltip}',
   nodeFormat: '{point.name}: {point.name}'

I have changed that in your fiddle as above and it returns FoorBall: FootBall when I mouse over on First Bar.

2. You need to write [nodeFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/6.0.2/series.sankey.tooltip.nodeFormatter) function to parse each points. This is a callback function for defining the format for nodes and defaults to `undefined`.

Comment: then it is much easier to achive. Create a stringOfWeights(e.g. 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12) in createNode method before doing the same. and in nodeFormat: '{point.name}: {point.stringOfWeights}'

Comment: node.stringOfweights = function () {
                    var sumTo = 0,
                        sumFrom = 0;
                    each(node.linksTo, function (link) {
                        sumTo += link.weight;
                    });
                    each(node.linksFrom, function (link) {
                        sumFrom += link.weight;
                    });
                    return 'Naren 1,2';
                };
Did you try something like that?